# How to keep a secured DB of network passwords and access it programatically

Tags: java, security

I need a solution to store all my network passords in a secure database. For that, I was thinking of Keepass. Now once the kdb (keepass DB) or something similar has been created, I would like to access it programatically preferably via Java.

I was also thinking of developing my own solution. Its a client/server architecture. The server will store all the passwd in gpg format. The clients will have the private key for decrypting the password received from the server. Only the clients with the correct private key can get decrypt the passwords. The private key will be embedded within the program.

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: If I am using keepass, i don't know if it's possible to request a single entry. Also, the API of keepass looks WIP. Hence I proferred my own solution.